# Fitting data with exponential form

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm newbie in Mathematica .I'm trying to fit data that ( i think) best fits on a exponential function. My code:

```
data = {{1, 0.5}, {10, 0.25}, {20, 0.2}, {60, 0.14}, {100, 0.1}, {500,
     0.03}, {1000, 0.02}, {2000, 0.015}, {3000, 0.014}, {4000, 
    0.0125}};
line = FindFit[data, Exp[-bx], b, x]
```

but i get

`FindFit::nrlnum: The function value s not a list of real numbers with dimensions {10} at {b} = {1.}`

Any idea;

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
line = FindFit[data, Exp[-bx], b, x]
```

to

```
line = FindFit[data, Exp[-b*x], b, x]
```